# Stopping docker-compose when a subset of the containers are finished

Tags: docker-compose

## Code

Consider the following `docker-compose.yml` configuration:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  tests:
    image: tests
    tty: true
    depends_on:
        - "server"
    links:
      - "server:srv"
  client:
    image: client
    tty: true
    depends_on:
        - "server"
    links:
      - "server:srv"
  server:
    image: server
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
```

The `client` and `tests` containers run until finished. The `server` container runs indefinitely.

## My Problem

I would like to run `docker-compose` till both the tests and client containers are done and set the exit status of docker-compose to 0 if (and only if) both ended up successfully. Upon failure, I expect any arbitrary error code to return.

## What have I tried

```
docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml up --exit-code-from tests
```

This runs till `tests` are finished, but does not wait for the `client`.

```
docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml up --exit-code-from tests client
```

Does not work.

## My Question

**How can I run `docker-compose` and let it wait till a specific set of containers are finished, and set its success exit code iff all finished successfully?**

Comment: I don't think this is possible with just native tools and flags to wait for a list of containers to finish before bringing the third one down. You may end up writing your own wrapping script that would periodically checks the status of `client` and `tests` and then terminates the server.